# iOS implement the file browser push same view controller show error

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, uitableview, browser

I need create the file browser function using the UITableViewController.

I load the data in the tableview, if user selected row at index path is a folder,

I want to push the same data structure and uitableview and using reload tableview to change the data show in the save view controller.

So I try to add

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];
```

in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method.

All method code :

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];
 }
```

But I got the error log is below

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
 reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported
```

I using pushViewController because the iOS can show the back to preview file title and have  navigation animate.

Have anyone can teach me how to resolve the problem or have some better function implement method?

thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you want to push same viewController again? Why you just didn't change dataSource of tableView? 
You can implement you own back button what will change dataSource back after user press on it

Comment: because I change the data source and reload, it is can't show view controller between view controller the animate. So I think push a new view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for it - it's allocate new instance of your class and push it into navigationController, instead of pushing `self`

Something like that:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     YourController *controller = [[YourController alloc] init]
     [self.navigationController pushViewController: controller animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: I try to using your hint, I will get the black screen unless the navigation bar.

Comment: okey , I try other method, using mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myVC"]; then push the vc, it is can push the same view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewController"] animated: YES];
```